# When having different installation executables which should be used?

Tags: installation, setup

I have noticed that many times a large program would have different executables which should do more or less the same thing (and they do more or less the same thing), as for example: Setup.exe, Install.exe, Setup_myProgram.exe, Initialize.exe, Autorun.exe,...

Is there a de-facto standard to which one should initiate the installation process and why are they so many and yet do the same thing?

Note that i have given examples with windows executables but a similar thing can also be observed on unix based systems.

Comment: Most of those files are created my the program that compiles and configures the behavior of the installer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, if you have commercial software, you should refer to the documentation to determine which executable should be run for normal installation.

In my experience, using the autorun feature of an installation medium (CD or DVD) will be the "default" installation.

For downloaded software, I generally run `setup.exe` if I have doubt and cant find documentation (either in the form of a readme file or online documentation).

**Further information:**

Usually some of these files will be "internal" files that either provide administrators with command line options for installing the software silently, over a network, using remote management software or with special properties that differ from the defaults.

In some cases, one or more of these files will be installers for a certain runtime environment, plugins or other external parts of the application package, that are bundled with the software.